# Is there any opportunity to add an assertion message in Rest Assured method?

Tags: java, rest-assured, hamcrest

Is there any opportunity to add assertion message into my method using libraries of Rest Assured? For example, I want to write an assertion message in this chain method without using System.out.println().

```
given().spec(requestSpecBuilder).when().get(commentsEndPoint).then().
            spec(responseSpecification).assertThat().contentType(ContentType.JSON.withCharset("UTF-8"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Rest-Assured doesn't have any methods like this.

To add assertion message, you can use Hamcrest directly.

```
Response res = given().when().get("your_url");
assertThat("Check status code", res.statusCode(), Matchers.is(200));
```

Comment: First, it's not constructor. Second, class `MatcherAssert` has this method `public static <T> void assertThat(String reason, T actual, Matcher<? super T> matcher)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use org.hamcrest.Matchers.describedAs() to add assertion message:

> ```
>     given().spec(requestSpecBuilder).when().get(commentsEndPoint).then().
>             spec(responseSpecification)
>             .contentType(describedAs("Error message",
>                     equalTo(ContentType.JSON.withCharset("UTF-8"))));
> ```